# Name of comic book about steam punk-ish parallel universe

Tags: story-identification, comics, parallel-universe, steampunk

I want to find the name of a comic I read in 1990-ies- it begins with a man piloting his spaceship, he crashes and wakes up in a different world- it's set somewhere between Victorian and 1930-ies, but our myths are a reality- there is a man with bunch of twigs on the moon, the world is flat, etc.
A major moment in the story was when the protagonist got a telescope to investigate the world. A whole page was filled with one drawing of what he saw- the flat world, tiny man on the moon and others.

I remember that the protagonist was living at an inventors mansion, full of cats. 
The inventor was trying to invent an airplane. The inventors' test flight failed, he crashed and was assumed dead. However, he soon turned up at his mansion, trying to cure the cold he had caught when falling into the sea.

There were NO aliens, robots, spirits/gods, nothing like that. It wasn't the unrealistic, shiny steam punk world either. It was more like turn of the 19th/20th century technology-wise, there were some "normal" early cars.

The book was translated in Latvian from French, if I'm not mistaken.

The drawings were rather realistic, not many bright colors, no black outlines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be this:
[L'autre_monde](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2235977.L_autre_monde)

I don't remember the part about seeing a man on the moon, but the rest of the description fits pretty well: Flat earth, storks bring the babies, and they actually face a crises about the sky literally falling to the ground.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the one! Particularly, this image - https://www.bedetheque.com/media/Versos/Verso_22823.jpg
Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I have these books myself (danish version), they really are some beautiful illustrated stories.